# Scala Pattern Matching with Sets

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

The following doesn't work.

```
object Foo {
    def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = t match {
        case isEmpty => s
        case (x:xs)  => union(s + x, xs)
        case _       => throw new Error("bad input")
    }
}
```

> error: not found: type xs

How can I pattern match over a set?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, `x:xs` means `x` of type `xs`, so it wouldn't work. But, alas, you can't pattern match sets, because sets do not have a defined order. Or, more pragmatically, because there's no extractor on `Set`.

You can always define your own, though:

```
object SetExtractor {
  def unapplySeq[T](s: Set[T]): Option[Seq[T]] = Some(s.toSeq)
}
```

For example:

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3) match {
     |   case SetExtractor(x, xs @ _*) => println(s"x: $x\nxs: $xs")
     | }
x: 1
xs: ArrayBuffer(2, 3)
```

Comment: Nice.  Just to be clear for Kevin: since there is no defined order on Sets, you should *not* use SetExtractor with actual values, e.g. `case SetExtractor( 1, xs @ _* ) => ...`; it happens to work with `Set(1,2,3)` but won't work generally, e.g. with `Set(1,2,3,4,5)`. Daniel is offering this as a way of allowing a deconstructing bind to pick an arbitrary element from a Set.  Also note that the remainder, xs, is an ArrayBuffer, so if you want it as a Set use `xs.toSet`.

Answer (score 7):

`Set` is not a `case class` and doesn't have a `unapply` method.

These two things imply that you cannot pattern match directly on a `Set`.
(**update**: unless you define your own *extractor* for `Set`, as Daniel correctly shows in his answer)

You should find an alternative, I'd suggest using a fold function

```
def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = 
    (s foldLeft t) {case (t: Set[Int], x: Int) => t + x}
```

or, avoiding most explicit type annotation

```
def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] =
  (s foldLeft t)( (union, element) => union + element )
```

or even shorter

```
def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] =
  (s foldLeft t)(_ + _)
```

This will accumulate the elements of `s` over `t`, adding them one by one

---

**folding**

Here are the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set) for the fold operation, if needed for reference:

```
foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this set, going left to right.

Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered. or the operator is associative and commutative.

```
B the result type of the binary operator.
z the start value.
op the binary operator.
returns the result of inserting op between consecutive elements of this set, going left to right with the start value z on the left:

op(...op(z, x_1), x_2, ..., x_n)
where x1, ..., xn are the elements of this set.
```

Comment: so if the `Set` class has no `unappy()` method, then it can't be decomposed via a match?

Comment: Correct, an object which has the `unapply(...)` method is called an *extractor*, and its purpose is to define how to extract its parameters in a `match/case` block. This comes automatic for `case classes`. If possible, you should see *ch.26* of "Programming in Scala 2nd ed." for reference.

Comment: As a Scala newbie, I spent some time puzzling over the syntax of that fold function. I found the second line easier to understand when I wrote it as `t.foldLeft(s)((s, t_el) => s + t_el)` because that matches the definition (besides, in this case, being more concise)

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin I can't remember why I wrote it so explicitly, but I'm gonna update the answer following your advice

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your `isEmpty` will catch every `Set` since it's a variable in this context. Constants start with an upper case letter in Scala and are treated only as constants if this condition holds. So lowercase will assign any `Set` to `isEmpty` (were you looking for `EmptySet`?)

As seen [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6252), it seems that pattern matching isn't very preferable for `Set`s. You should probably explicitly convert the `Set` to a `List` or `Seq` (`toList` / `toSeq`)

```
object Foo {
    def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = t.toList match {
        case Nil => s
        case (x::xs)  => union(s + x, xs.toSet)
        case _       => throw new Error("bad input")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also backticked things that also matched by value.

Comment: is there any slowness involved due to the conversion of a `Set` to a `List`?

Comment: Yes. You can use pagoda's solution for performance purposes. I just wanted to show you how to do it with pattern matching. By the way, in my example, the `_` case is never reached

Answer (score 2):

This is what I can come up with:

```
object Contains {
  class Unapplier[T](val t: T) {
    def unapply(s: Set[T]): Option[Boolean] = Some(s contains t)
  }
  def apply[T](t: T) = new Unapplier(t)
}

object SET {
  class Unapplier[T](val set: Set[T]) {
    def unapply(s: Set[T]): Option[Unit] = if (set == s) Some(Unit) else None
  }
  def apply[T](ts: T*) = new Unapplier(ts.toSet)
}

val Contains2 = Contains(2)
val SET123 = SET(1, 2, 3)

Set(1, 2, 3) match {
  case SET123()         => println("123")
  case Contains2(true)  => println("jippy")
  case Contains2(false) => println("ohh noo")
}
```

Comment: also see: [Coding in Style: How to wield Scala in the trenches](http://parleys.com/play/52a11b33e4b039ad2298ca78/chapter58/about) at 0:39:45

Answer (score 1):

```
    t match {
      case s if s.nonEmpty => // non-empty 
      case _ => // empty
    }
```