# Scala Set match case

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning scala and as the best training I'm transforming my old Java Algorithms to functional programming style. I have the following code:

```
def test(originalSet: Set[Int]):Boolean = originalSet match {
    case Set()  => true
    case x::y => false
  }
```

This code works fine for Lists, but for Sets it gives me the following compilation errors:

```
  - value Set is not a case class constructor, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq 
         method
```

and

```
- constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: 
     scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
    - constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: 
     scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

What is the problem? How can I test the case that the Set is empty? and how can I the other case when set has head and tail?

Comment: Test is a very bad name for that code - why don't you name it isEmpty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Set` defines an `isEmpty` method so the simplest solution is

```
def test(originalSet: Set[Int]): Boolean = originalSet.isEmpty
```

When you match against a List using

```
list match {
    case Nil => true
    case x :: y => false
}
```

you are matching against the List `Nil` object and against the `::` class i.e. it is equivalent to

```
list match {
    case Nil => true
    case ::(x, y) => false
}
```

So you can't use this form with `Set`.

When you pattern match against a List using:

```
list match {
    case List(a, b) => true
    case _ => false
}
```

you are using the List extractor. The `List` extractor is defined using `unapplySeq` which matches if the list is of the given format. `Set` does not define an `unapply` or `unapplySeq` method, so you can't match against it in this way either.

Answer (score 3):

This question is kind of old but I am surprised that none of the answers gives a solution that allows to pattern match.

In order to preserve the `Set` semantics and be able to pattern match, you will need to implement a custom `unapply` method that takes a `Set` for input. This is a very useful pattern that can be applied to about just any type.

```
object EmptySet {
  def unapply[A](s: Set[A]): Boolean = s.isEmtpy
}

object NonEmptySet {
  def unapply[A](s: Set[A]): Option[Set[A]] = 
    if (s.isEmpty) None
    else Some(s)
}

def foo(bars: Set[Int]): String = bars match {
  case EmptySet => "No Bars"
  case NonEmptySet(values) => s"Bars: $values"
}
```

The pattern is described here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html

Comment: NonEmptySet should have two parameters, which selects a single element and the remaining (optionally empty) set.

Answer (score 2):

Set does not have an unapply method, nor Seq so it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a case deconstructor on them.  (ref [Scala Pattern Matching with Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163904/scala-pattern-matching-with-sets)) .. But I'll add my own note, I've been learning scala and initially thought that case match should be used for everything - but it's perfectly acceptable to use if- then statements in functional programming, and would make the most sense here.

```
def test(originalSet: Set[Int]):Boolean = ! originalSet.isEmpty
```