# Scala list match for type and size

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do some patting matching in Scala and I'm running into some problems. Here's my code (minus the fluff):

```
realtionships.filter(...) match {
    case (parent: Relationship) :: Nil => parent.endNode
    case _ => throw new Exception
}
```

The gist is that I want a list that is only a single item that is of type `Relationship`. If it's anything else, throw an Exception. But the compiler is giving me this error:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type
found: scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
required: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Relationship]
```

Why exactly am I getting this error? Am I not allowed to match the elements of a list while also trying to match the type? Or do I just have the wrong syntax? (Side note: Relationship is a case class.)

Comment: Though, on second thought match is complete, and the code snippet in question should compile. Are you sure the error is relevant to provided code piece?

Comment: As dmitry said: It should compile.. Please post the fluff.

Comment: So, my first idea that you have a Set was right, seems semantics of :: requires matching sequence to be List. If you say, change first line to `case List(parent: Relationship) => ...` it would compile. Though if you match Set it will throw, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will refuse a pattern match if it can deduce that you are trying to match types which cannot be equal. From the error message is appears that `relationships` is a `Set` and you are trying to match for a `List`. Now a `Set` can never be a `List`, so the compiler rightfully rejects that code.

If you *want* a `List` actually, you can enforce it:

```
relationships.filter(...).toList match {
  ..
}
```

If you want to stick to a `Set`, you would need an extractor on `Set`. That doesn't exist, however... [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163904/scala-pattern-matching-with-sets) related with an answer that shows you to write a custom extractor. If you don't want to go through this effort, a poor man's solution would be

```
val f = relationships.filter(...)
f.headOption match {
  case Some(parent: Relationship) if f.size == 1 => parent.endNode
  case _ => throw new Exception
}
```

(Note however that `size` is an O(N) operation)

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid. The error was clear as day and I missed it. :/ I was trying to match a set. Iterables are so interchangeable in Scala that I sometimes forget that they really are different. Thank you so much.